# Cannot get in onReceive method of BroadcastReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am using an Alarm manager to call a notification on a receiver method. I put some debug code in it, and found that the process didn't even get in there.

Here are my codes:

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Menu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ContentInput"
        />

    <receiver
        android:process=":remote"
        android:name=".NoticationBroadcast"/>
</application>
```

Menu.java (the main class)

```
Button noti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noti);
noti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e(ErrorTag, "before onclick");
        scheduleNotification(getNotification("ggggg"),2000);
        Log.e(ErrorTag, "after onclick");
    }
});

private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

    Log.e(ErrorTag, "finish get notificattion");

    return builder.build();
}

private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NoticationBroadcast.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NoticationBroadcast.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NoticationBroadcast.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Log.e(ErrorTag, "after getBroadcast");

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    Log.e(ErrorTag, "after alarm");

}
```

Receiver class

```
public class NoticationBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("ERROR", "beginning of on receive");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        Log.e("ERROR", "end of on receive");
    }
}
```

Edit:

I changed a line of the code

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

to

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (5000), pendingIntent);
```

It is working perfectly. But I don't know why is it. If anyone has know what happened, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: I think your approach is wrong.Correct me if i'm wrong. You are sending notification object to broadcast receiver which may not work.Try using service for notification.

Comment: you can get lot tutorials for simple alarm manager with notification on google.

Comment: I think i solved it. But I don't know what did i I do :O

Comment: Cool. I will try this approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

You are scheduling a job to run exactly now, which, obviously, won't be fired.

Whereas in the second version (working version), you are scheduling a job 5000 ms later than now:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                 + (5000), pendingIntent);
```

Changing to this would work as expected:

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 5000, 
                      pendingIntent);
```